# Обособление "как наяву"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужно ли обособление "как наяву" в данном предложении?

> Это всё было как наяву.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, потому что сочетание слов «как наяву» является сказуемым.

Comment: Что есть ЭТО? Почему оно, ЭТО, сказуемое? По жизни или временами?

Comment: Вопрос был: «Нужно ли обособление "как наяву" в данном предложении?», а ответ был: «Нет, потому что это сказуемое».